# What do I do with JSON data?

Tags: json

I know, a very newbie question...

I'm creating a forum on JCink. They let you customise user profiles, but it gives you some data in JSON format. I have a vague idea of what JSON is, but I'm really sure what I'm supposed to do with it. I want to make it look a certain way, but I have no idea how to get started.

Could anyone help me figure it out? I tried searching Google for what I'm supposed to do with this data, but it didn't really help... ^^;

The code I'm being given is this:

```
[
  {
    "contact_id": "3",
    "friend_avatar": "http://pjonline.b1.jcink.com/uploads/pjonline/av-3.jpg",
    "friend_name": "acetest",
    "posts": "2",
    "active": "3 Nov 2016, 06:32:23"
  }
]
```

And I want to make it look like this: http://prntscr.com/d2pbks

I don't need you to flat out do it for me, but some pointers on what I even *do* with this JSON data would be super great.

Comment: Maybe you could take some time and [learn JSON](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp)?

Comment: @BryndenBielefeld Yeah, I've been reading up on it. It's making me dizzy... I know nothing of Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically want to render data in HTML. You'd have to parse the object and render it how you want. According to JCLink documentation you're provided the JSON object. So all you have to do is take that data and render it.

Something like this. This doesn't render it how you want but you can modify the HTML and CSS to do what you want.

```js
var jsonData = [{
  "contact_id": "3",
  "friend_avatar": "http://pjonline.b1.jcink.com/uploads/pjonline/av-3.jpg",
  "friend_name": "acetest",
  "posts": "2",
  "active": "3 Nov 2016, 06:32:23"
},{
  "contact_id": "5",
  "friend_avatar": "http://pjonline.b1.jcink.com/uploads/pjonline/av-2.jpg",
  "friend_name": "dingo",
  "posts": "8675309",
  "active": "1 Nov 2016, 06:32:23"
}];

var htmlOut = "";

for (var i = 0, numProfiles = jsonData.length; i < numProfiles; ++i) {
  var thisData = jsonData[i];
  htmlOut += "<div>";
  htmlOut += "<h1>" + thisData.friend_name + "</h1>";
  htmlOut += "<img src='" + thisData.friend_avatar + "' />";
  htmlOut += "<br />";
  htmlOut += "posts: " + thisData.posts;
  htmlOut += "<br />";
  htmlOut += "active: " + thisData.active;
  htmlOut += "</div>";
}

document.getElementById("profiles").innerHTML = htmlOut;
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Friends</h1>
  <div id="profiles"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah! That... almost worked! Just, how would I make it dynamic to different users? After all, not everyone is going to have the same amount of friends or the same friends, if any at all.

Comment: Well that would depend on the JSON data you get right? It would/should have the details for each user and you would just render it.

Comment: Ah, yeah! I just realised there was a field I can input that'll give friend data. Thank you soooo much! I was getting worried I'd have to just remove these features!!

Answer (score 1):

JSON can be a bit tricky if you've never used it. I use it a lot and it still stumps me sometimes, so no worries! JSON is JavaScript Object Notation, and is used heavily for things like ajax. Explaining the entirety of JSON here isn't practical, so [here](https://www.copterlabs.com/json-what-it-is-how-it-works-how-to-use-it/) is a site that may be helpful to you. [This](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/) is also a valuable tool that I use to visualize complicated JSON objects.

Now, the image that you posted isn't going to come straight from JSON. That is a combination of HTML, CSS and JavaScript so your question may be broader than just JSON. JSON simply acts as a container for the information to display, or a model. If there is something about JSON that you don't understand after reading, feel free to ask a more specific question and I'll do my best to help!

Comment: Hmm... Yeah, I guess my issue is trying to figure out how I would customise it with HTML/CSS/JavaScript. Maybe I should change the thread title o-o But ty for those links!! I'll look at them and see what I can do.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var json = {"contact_id":"3","friend_avatar":"http:\/\/pjonline.b1.jcink.com\/uploads\/pjonline\/av-3.jpg","friend_name":"acetest","posts":"2","active":"3 Nov 2016, 06:32:23"};
document.write('contact_id:' + json.contact_id);
```

So you want to render the value into your HTML?

Since the JSON is valid object you don't need to parse it, otherwise if its a string then you'll need to `JSON.parse(json)`.

Something like this, but of course this is just an example how to output json in your html. Pretty sure putting the values in `divs` would be pretty easy.

```
var json = {"contact_id":"3","friend_avatar":"http:\/\/pjonline.b1.jcink.com\/uploads\/pjonline\/av-3.jpg","friend_name":"acetest","posts":"2","active":"3 Nov 2016, 06:32:23"};
document.write(json.contact_id);
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/MyiE16jLtM2g6xRlCocb?p=preview

Comment: Ah, the thing is, the code I get is an output from a value I insert into the editor.

Comment: then if the JSON is in a text editor, you'd need to get the value then `JSON.parse()` as it will be a string then do the same as the example above, otherwise if its an array of objects then you'd need to do a `for()` see @IMTheNachoMan example.